# Extra Spacing in List iOS 14 SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui, ios14

I am trying to remove the outer space (marked in red) from ListView.

This issue appeared in iOS 14 and Xcode 12 GM.

Here is the code I am using:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var menuItems:[String] = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
    
    var body: some View {
        List(self.menuItems, id:\.self) { title in
            MenuRow(title: title)
        }
    }
}

struct MenuRow:View {
    var title:String
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
            Text(title)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    .font(Font.system(size: 14,
                            weight: .regular,
                            design: .default))
            Spacer()
            Text(title)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    .font(Font.system(size: 14,
                            weight: .regular,
                            design: .default))
            
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
        .background(Color.white)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you want custom layouts I strongly recommend using a LazyVStack + ScrollView (in addition to the ForEach from the answer below). The default `List` control have built-in styling that's very hard to remove.

Comment: But then you lose many List features and mostly you lose cell reusability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `.listRowInsets` to work you need to use a `ForEach` inside a `List`:

```
List {
    ForEach(self.menuItems, id:\.self) {
        MenuRow(title: $0)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can remove duplicated `listRowInsets` as it is already present inside `MenuRow`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  For the list add:

```
List {
    ...
}
.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 23)
```